# Unity реализация загрузки файлов из выбранной пользователем папки

Tags: c#, unity3d

Можно ли реализовать такой сценарий, при котором пользователь при клике по кнопке `button` попадает на форму загрузки файлов, которая позволяет ему выбрать папку расположения файла так, как это реализовано сейчас в windows? Т.е. пользователю не нужно самостоятельно что-то вставлять в форум загрузки, к примеру, копировать адрес папки, в которой находится файл, а именно с помощью самой формы загрузки он сможет путешествовать по папкам компьютера, чтобы выбрать нужную?

Comment: Я точно знаю что такое можно потому что видел как это делают. Но я сам этого не делал поэтому не смогу помочь. Извините...

Comment: Тоже не сталкивался с таким, но нагуглилась такая ссылка на [ассет](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/file-selection-dialogue-11374). Посмотрите, может подойдет?

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский так даже можно скачать ассет и посмотреть как он написан и так сделать свой

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский, спасибо за ссылку, изучу это расширение

Comment: @Alt_F4, я тут в API нашла что-то, похоже это, то что мне нужно? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.OpenFolderPanel.html

Comment: @Volha очень похоже. Почему бы нет, можете попробовать. И если это то что вам нужно, то я вам обещаю положительный голос от меня, потому что такой вопрос я задавал уже третий раз, но не получил нормального ответа. Прошу мне сообщить о результатах.

Comment: @Volha Только используйте OpenFilePanel а не OpenFolderPanel. Вот ссылка - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel.html

Answer (score 1):

Нашла решение именно своей задачи. Т.е. при клике по button открывается  окно с возможностью выбора файла в папке windows. В итоге получаю ссылку на путь, по которому располагается файл, т.к. для моей задачи нужно было именно это (ну и сам файл тоже нужен).

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
```

Метод для кнопки:

```
public void LoadFile()

{        

    string path = EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("Overwrite with xml", "", "xml");
    if (path.Length != 0)
    {

        Debug.Log(path);
    }

}
```

вместо xml нужно указать необходимый формат файла
[Ccылка на API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel.html)

Comment: `EditorUtility` не работает в билдах

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, да, действительно, работает только в редакторе, только что проверила. Это ужасно, но с этим придется смириться( Значит буду искать другое решение. Пока только нашла, как открыть проводник windows -  `Application.OpenURL("C://");`  как сохранить путь к выбранному файлу буду искать

Comment: Какая ОС? Win? Файловый проводник - не самая тривиальная задача, но в целом ничего сложного нет, как только узнаю ОС - смогу оформить ответ.

Comment: да, windows, ответьте, пожалуйста, очень нужно! в конечном счете мне в методе нужно узнать путь к файлу, который открывает пользователь в проводнике windows

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, я могу надеяться на ваш вариант решения?

Comment: Можете, но как только у меня появится свободное время на ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Знаю, что отвечаю через год, но я нашёл решение: [GitHub](https://github.com/gkngkc/UnityStandaloneFileBrowser). Работает даже в билдах.

Из ссылки достаточно скопировать *Assets/StandaloneFileBrowser/Plugins* для возможности открытия форм под разные OS и *Assets/StandaloneFileBrowser/все скрипты не в папках* для  создания namespace SFB. Все возможные команды можно посмотреть в
*Assets/StandaloneFileBrowser/Sample/BasicSample.cs*

```
using UnityEngine;
using SFB; //namespace из ссылки

public class Inspector : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void OpenFile()
    {
        var extensions = new [] {  //какие файлы вообще можно открыть
            new ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "png", "jpg", "jpeg" ),
            new ExtensionFilter("All Files", "*" ),
        };
        foreach(string path in StandaloneFileBrowser.OpenFilePanel("Open File", "", extensions, true))
        { //открытие формы для загрузки файла
            Debug.Log(path);
        }
    }
}
```

Код выше откроет форму загрузки изображений для *Windows*, *Linux* или *Mac* и выведет путь в консоль.

Comment: Если во время билдинга возникли ошибки, то убедитесь, что _Edit/Project Settings/Player/Api Compatibility Level_ поставлен на .NET 4,x для Unity 2018.3.11f1 и выше, или .NET 2.0 для более ранних, если всё ещё выдаёт ошибку, то поставьте в папку с плагинами: [System.Configuration.dll](https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/system_configuration_dll.html)